# Searching an Array in Word (Visual Basic for Applications)

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I have set up three arrays in Word. The arrays are as follows:

```
tacData = Array("32064600", "33001000", "33001100", "33002400", "33003000", "33002400", "35011001", "35013200", "35124100", "35124100")
makeData = Array("Alcatel", "Alcatel", "Sagem", "Samsung", "AEG Mobile", "Samsung", "Nokia", "Maxon", "Siemes", "Nokia")
modelData = Array("One Touch EasyHD", "91009109MB2", "RC410G14", "SGH-200", "Sharp TQ6", "SGH-5300", "DCT-3", "MX6832", "MC399 Cellular Termnial", "DCT-4")
```

I have made a user form which get a TAC (Value) from the User. Can I get this value and search for it in the **first** array and get its ID so that I can get the make and model from the other two arrays? I have tried using some code samples that I found but they do not seem to work with Word throwing errors. They were things like Application.Match.

On a side note, would there be a better way to store this information rather than three arrays?

Comment: I noticed the TAC "33002400" is defined twice, making it unsuitable for a collection object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a collection object. Look at the code below

```
Dim tacData() As Variant, makeData() As Variant, modelData() As Variant
tacData = Array("32064600", "33001000", "33001100", "33002400", "33003000", "33002401", "35011001", "35013200", "35124100", "35124101")
makeData = Array("Alcatel", "Alcatel", "Sagem", "Samsung", "AEG Mobile", "Samsung", "Nokia", "Maxon", "Siemes", "Nokia")
modelData = Array("One Touch EasyHD", "91009109MB2", "RC410G14", "SGH-200", "Sharp TQ6", "SGH-5300", "DCT-3", "MX6832", "MC399 Cellular Termnial", "DCT-4")

Dim i As Integer, N As Integer
N = UBound(tacData, 1) 'Get the data size
Dim item As Phone      'Temp variable for creating elements into a collection

Dim list As New VBA.Collection  'Define a new collection
For i = 1 To N
    Set item = New Phone        'Assign a new Phone object
    With item
        .TAC = tacData(i)       'Assign values to the phone
        .Make = makeData(i)
        .Model = modelData(i)
    End With
    list.Add item, item.TAC     'Add the phone to the list with a KEY
    Set item = Nothing
Next i

Dim TAC As String
TAC = "33002400"                'get user input

Set item = list(TAC)            '** lookup Phone using Key **

If Not item Is Nothing Then     ' Show results
    Debug.Print item.TAC, item.Make, item.Model
Else
    Debug.Print "Not Found"
End If
```

It works with a new class called 'Phone' containing

```
Option Explicit    
Public TAC As String
Public Make As String
Public Model As String
```

and inserted into VBA via this menu item, and renaming in the project tree as "Phone"
[image]

The requirement is that the 'TAC' code is unique. In your case it wasn't and I had to change some numbers to make them unique. How have to consider what to do if in real life there are multiple phones with the same `TAC` code.

PS. Welcome to the world of object oriented programming. This was your first step.